# Ruby String mismatch in while comparing text from a text file

Tags: ruby, file, text

I am in a problem while reading a text file with readline and trying to compare first line with a string. I want to compare the first line of the text file with a string and then will go for next process. But I can't do that. Here is my code:

```
doc = File.open("example.txt", "r")
line1 = doc.readline
if line1 == "sukanta"   
  line2 = doc.readline 
  line3 = doc.readline 
  line4 = doc.readline 
end
```

My `example.txt` file contains:

```
sukanta  
Software engineer
label2  
server:107.108.9.190
```

Please give me solution. While I am trying to get string length with `line1.length` it's not showing the exact number. 
i got the answer. Its silly mistake .. i should use "sukanta\n" to compare

When i am using readline to read each line then i have to set each line in their place sequentially. i cant break the order. Whil i am using loop like

```
doc = File.open("example.txt", "r")
doc.each_line do |lines|
 puts lines
end
```

getting the whole text as a line. cant separate each line from others. i need to break the order. How to do that?

Comment: Posting [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are not taking into account that a line ends with `$/` (`"\n"` on UNIX). So you probably intended

```
line1 == "sukanta\n"
```

or

```
line1.chomp == "sukanta"
```

and you are not including `$/` when you count the length (which is one or two characters less than the correct length depending on the OS).

Comment: Should've been a comment, maybe?

Comment: [doc = File.open("example.txt", "r")
    doc.each_line do |lines|
    puts lines
    end]  cant separate lines from each other